# Mock test return null in spring CrudRepository test

Tags: spring, jpa, mocking

```
<implements class>
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {
    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository repo;

    public void createService(Customer customer){
        System.out.println("Service Create");
        repo.createCustomer(customer.getId(),customer.getName(),customer.getPassword(),customer.getGender(),customer.getAddress());
    }
    public Customer readService(Customer customer){
        System.out.println("Service Read");
        return repo.readCustomer(customer.getId(), customer.getPassword());
    }
}
```

```
<Repository interface>
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer,Long>{
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "insert into customer (id,name,password,gender,address) VALUES (:id,:name,:password,:gender,:address)", nativeQuery = true)
    void createCustomer(@Param("id") String id, @Param("name") String name, @Param("password") Integer password, @Param("gender") String gender, @Param("address") String address);

    @Query(value = "select * from customer where id = :id and password = :password", nativeQuery = true)
    Customer readCustomer(@Param("id") String id, @Param("password") Integer password);
}
```

```
<Service interface>
@Service
public interface CustomerService{
    public void createService(Customer customer);
    public Customer readService(Customer customer);
}
```

```
<Controller Class>
@RestController
public class CustomerController {
    @Autowired(required = false)
    CustomerServiceImpl customerServiceImpl = new CustomerServiceImpl();
    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository repo;
    @GetMapping("/api/create")
    public Customer createController(@RequestParam("id") String id, @RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("password") Integer password, @RequestParam("gender") String gender, @RequestParam("address") String address){
        Customer customer = new Customer(id, name, password, gender, address);
        customerServiceImpl.createService(customer);
        return customer;
    }
    @GetMapping("/api/read")
    public Customer readController(@RequestParam("id") String id, @RequestParam("password") Integer password){
        Customer customer = customerServiceImpl.readService(new Customer(id, password));
        if(null == customer){
            System.out.println("null");
            return null;
        }else{
            return customer;
        }
    }
}
```

```
<Test File>
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class CustomerTest {
    @Mock
    private Customer mockCustomer;
    @Mock
    private CustomerService mockCustomerService;
    @Mock
    private CustomerRepository mockCustomerRepository;
    @Test
    public void testReadServiceOk(){
        Customer mockCustomer = new Customer(idTest,passwordTest);
        CustomerServiceImpl mockCustomerServiceImpl = new CustomerServiceImpl();
        mockCustomer = mockCustomerServiceImpl.readService(mockCustomer);
    }
}
```

i wrote the code java crud project with Entity Customer Class,
Implements Class, Repoisotry interface, Service interface.
and i want test this with using mock.

i think i can test create mockCustomer(mock Customer Entity) and => call readService with mockCustomer
but it return null with error (this.repo is null)
is it have another solution ? i want to know how can i test it

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "jp.ksg.testproject.Repository.CustomerRepository.readCustomer(String, java.lang.Integer)" because "this.repo" is null
 at jp.ksg.testproject.Implements.CustomerServiceImpl.readService(CustomerServiceImpl.java:20)
 at jp.ksg.testproject.CustomerTest.testReadServiceOk(CustomerTest.java:107)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
```